# Should I add a "nofollow" attribute to download links, or disallow the URLs in robots.txt?

Tags: robots.txt, nofollow, download

I have a download link very similar to [Opera's one](http://www.opera.com/download/get.pl?id=33976&location=270&nothanks=yes&sub=marine) - it's just a script that sends the file. It doesn't have an extension and there's no obvious way to tell that it's actually a download link.

So since I don't want robots to crawl this link, do I need to add it to robots.txt or maybe add a "nofollow" attribute to it? I see that on Opera's website they didn't do either of this, so perhaps it's not necessary?

Answer (score 2):

There's no reason not to do both. You could consider requiring an Http-Referer from within your site too - the only bot I've seen which sends referrer headers isn't actually a spider but a distributed attempt to exploit the ASP.Net Viewstate oracle padding vulnerability.

I have one directory which I do this on. The .htaccess for that directory is

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST};%{HTTP_REFERER} !^([^;]+);http://\1(/.*)?$
RewriteRule .* /foro.htm [R]
```

(where /foro.htm is the page which links into the directory - that way people following links from other sites aren't completely messed up).

Answer (score 2):

Neither should actually be necessary. The 'extension' at the end of a file or URL is practically meaningless - it gives a hint to the filetype but obviously files can be named anything you like. On the web, the way to specify a file type is in the **mime type**, given through the `Content-type` HTTP header. For example, a JPEG image has the mime type `image/jpeg`.

Before downloading a file, a program will first check the 'HEAD' response from the server so it knows what to do with the content. Search engines do the same, and assuming you are sending correct headers (for example `application/zip` for .zip files or `application/octet-stream` for generic binary files) they will avoid downloading the actual content and stick to things they recognise like web pages and images.

Having said all this, it probably is best to block access to the URLs to be on the safe side. I would say **robots.txt** is the simplest and best way to do this. You can block the script or folder the script is in and that will apply for all future downloads you add, too.

Comment: While some search engines _might_ abort the request if the MIME type is something they can't handle, disallowing the download URLs in robots.txt would still be a good idea if you don't want them to request those URLs to begin with (e.g. if merely starting the request is expensive, or if it might have side effects you don't want robots to trigger).

Comment: @IlmariKaronen That's a good point about "starting the request" - if files are generated from a script then it's unlikely to send the header before the data is generated.

Answer (score 2):

To stop search engines and other robots from requesting certain URLs, you need to [disallow those URLs in your `robots.txt` file](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html).

Adding the `rel="nofollow"` attribute to links [might *not* actually stop robots from following those links](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/19216/nofollow-doesnt-stop-crawling) — it just tells search engines that those links should not be considered as endorsements of any kind, e.g. because they might have been added by untrusted third parties, and, in particular, that they should not be taken into account when calculating PageRank or other similar link metrics.  However, the exact details might vary between search engines, and possibly also over time for any given search engine.

There exists also the similarly name `nofollow` attribute for the [`robots` meta tag](http://www.robotstxt.org/meta.html) which does instruct compliant search engines not to follow *any* links from the tagged page.  However, that tag applies to all links on the page, not just to some particular ones.  Also, neither meta tags nor `rel="nofollow"` will stop search engines from crawling your download URLs if they find them through some link that they *are* allowed to follow, either because you forgot to put the tag on some page that links to the download URL, or because someone else copied the URL to another site.  Thus, in this situation, `robots.txt` is the only reliable solution.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to put nofollow on any links which are perfectly trustworthy, It's not needed, there's no reason to try and sculpt your page rank if that's what your aiming for.

From SEOMoz and Matt Cutts

**Does the Number of Outbound Links from a Page Affect PageRank?**

> For instance, to conserve "link juice" and/or funnel it more discretely, does it matter whether I have three outbound links versus
>   two? In the original PageRank formula, yes, juice flowed out in a
>   simple formula of Passable PR divided by number of outbound links. But
>   nowadays, Matt says it is a much more cyclical, iterative analysis
>   and, "it really doesn't make as much difference as people suspect."
>   There's no need to hoarde all of your link juice on your page and, in
>   fact, there may be benefit to generously linking out (not the least of
>   which is the link-building power of good will).

http://www.seomoz.org/blog/whiteboard-interview-googles-matt-cutts-on-redirects-trust-more

On the other hand are your trying to hide the download file from everyone but authorized users? If so you should be going about it another way using a script to initiate the download when the user is authorized.

If the file doesn't matter just link to it.

Answer (score 0):

While I understand your question, I am curious why you wouldn't want it indexed, I have recently been doing some reading on SEO for non-HTML documents (like .pdf and .docx).

Favoring transparency, I figure if it isn't a payment page or something of that sort (confidential info, not relevant to my site) then I may as well milk it for all it is worth, SEO-wise...and people love free stuff (like downloads).

Anyway, I think it is good practice to make it clear (normally visually) that download links are downloads (I am guessing by context that you already have by styling it as a download button or something). Further, while I don't know if it is still used by Yahoo! (or has been adopted by others) they utilize(d) (in 2008) [a 'noindex' class for some content](http://www.seobythesea.com/2008/07/which-sections-of-your-web-pages-might-search-engines-ignore/)